# A Magic Flying Saucer

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, calculation-puzzle, graph-theory

Place 19 different positive integers on the vertices of this graph so that the 13 products of three numbers in a straight line are all equal. Do so in such a way that the product is as small as possible.

[image]

Comment: There are several '3-in-a-row' in your diagram, e.g. top-middle, middle, bottom-middle. Do these count, or must they be on an actual line?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry The 13 products on actual lines.

Comment: Well, you could add a few then. OK's answer gives (4,7,10), (11, 7,3) and (14,7,0) as at least three more answers! (I suppose this messes with minimality though).

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, it would mess the minimum by a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Final Short Answer:

> [image]
>  Product = $720$

#### Derivation Process:

By observation, this graph is composed with many triangles, so that maybe "3" is the key to identify the "dimension" or "vector" concept.

By **[unique factorization theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-unique-prime-factorization-theorem)**, every positive integer can be represented as the product of prime numbers and this representation is **unique**.

Based on above 2 reasons, I tried to solve this question with the form $a^x b^y c^z$. And by the theorem, every unique tuple $(x,y,z)$ ensures that $a^x b^y c^z$ is also unique.

Thus for base $a,b,c$, I picked the smallest primes $2,3,5$. Then we need at least 19 different integers to fill in the vertex, so I began to try $x=y=z=2$ due to there are 27 unique integer candidates vary from $2^03^05^0$ to $2^23^25^2$, but not working.

Then I tried with $x=y=z=3$, and it works :P

[image]

$(x,y,z)$ denotes the integer $2^x3^y5^z$, ex: $(1,1,2) \to 2^13^15^2 = 150$
The tuple/vector summation for all lines are $(3,3,3)$, hence the product is $2^33^35^3 = 27,000$

**Improved:**

Well, thanks the hint from question owner, I now tried out with the form $2^x3^y$:

[image]

Since the graph is line-symmetry, so that vertex which are on the center line should have $x=y$ property, and the rest should be symmetric, forming the property $(x,y) \to (y,x)$, from left to right.

Thus now the minimum product is reduced to $2^53^5 = 7,776$

**Improved again:**

This time I abandoned the symmetry approach due to some lower vector $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are not used, $(x,y)$ need to be more "compact" when fill in the vertex.

Thus I attempted to put some lowers like $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ in joint vertex and put some highers like $(4,3)$ or $(3,4)$ in side vertex, and worked out:

[image]

Now the minimum is reduced again to $2^43^4 = 1,296$
I hope it is the final optimal answer and worth at least 30 upvotes :P

**Improved again & again:**

Need to reduce once more. Based on the upper limit $2^43^4 = 1,296$, I've listed all possibilities for the minimum which product is lower than $1,296$ and integer candidates are at least 20(due to we need 19 different integers to fill in):

- $2^23^25^17^1 = 1,260 (36)$
- $2^73^2 = 1,152 (24)$
- $2^33^35^1 = 1,080 (32)$
- $2^23^25^2 = 900 (27)$
- $2^53^3 = 864 (24)$
- $2^43^25^1 = 720 (30)$
- $2^63^2 = 576 (21)$
- $2^43^3 = 432 (20)$
- $2^23^15^17^1 = 420 (24)$
- $2^33^25^1 = 360 (24)$

And begin try and error process, finally worked out one:

[image]

Now the minimum is reduced again & again to $2^43^25^1 = 720$
I hope it's the optimal minimum :(

Comment: Nice, but not the minimum known to me.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Is the answer closer to the minimum or still far away? :P

Comment: Not far, and uses precisely the ideas you are trying.

Comment: You could try (4,3,2), which is less than (3,3,3)

Comment: @Conifers Nearly there!

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos I got some idea, wait me for a while :P

Comment: @Conifers Not there yet, but very close!

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Okay I'll try again~ (I need to update answer in home due to I couldn't upload the image on outside working PC, wait me a while :P)

Comment: Hmm still working on it :(

Comment: @Conifers No hurry, take your time.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos I just checked your profile found that you are the math teacher! I am curious about if any mathematical property or concept could be applied on such this question to help find the minimum product or fill in the integers quickly? I just think like coloring problem or prime labeling may help, but need someone's comment due to I am not major in math :P

Comment: @Conifers No, I don´t know of any straightforward way of finding the minimum. In fact, I was surprised (and shocked!) to see you had lowered the minimum I had in mind (1080). I start from abundant numbers and construct plausible magic graphs using their many divisors. I don´t really know how to go backwards efficiently other then by pondered trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by another answer in another similar genre of question (forgot which one but I think the answer is by @Deusovi), this problem can be simplified to addition and then changing each number n in the circle to $4^n$ to achieve the task. Apparently this isn’t the optimal one, because the total product of all the numbers is

> 341704645

While the total product of each line is

> $4^{13}$

The diagram of n’s [The lines are somehow missing `:(`]:

> [image]

The Excel of conversion:

> [image]

Comment: Can I see 8, 7.5, 4.5 (=20)? (right side)

Comment: @Jon should be 8.5 instead of 7.5, will update later, thanks!